# Split only part of list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, get

I have a list

```
['Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain', 'Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins', 'Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens']
```

i want split after keyword "boulevard, rue, chemin" like in output

```
['Saint-Germain', 'Camille Desmoulins', 'des Aubagnens']
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: That is a list not a dictionary, you also have single words and multiple words you want to get so splitting is not going to work

Comment: Have edited the initial list back, so that the bolded text appears as is...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Put an example of what is the expected output.

Comment: The expected output is in bold if people would stop editing it out

Comment: `'Paris, 458 **boulevard Saint-Germain**',` and `'Lille, 120 boulevard **Victor Hugo**'` I don't get the logic behind this.

Comment: @TheCoder, the fact you are calling a list a dictionary would lead one to believe that you have not really learnt the basics of python, I would suggest checking out the python-practice-book http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: For the love of God will people stop editing the question, the bolded content is what the OP is trying to get, there is already an answer using the `**` as a delimiter to split which is obviously not there

Comment: I expect something like that [Saint-Germain', 'Camille Desmoulins', 'des Aubagnens', 'des singes', 'VoLtAiRe', 'Voltaire', 'Victor Hugo', 'Voltaire', 'Voltaire', 'du Bouclier', 'de la lib\xc3\xa9ration', 'Victor Danel', 'de Bordeaux', 'Pierre de Coubertin', 'de Nancy', 'du Docteur Alb\xc3\xa9ric Pont', 'd\xe2\x80\x99Arras', 'Georges Pompidou', 'des fleurs']

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression (e.g. https://regex101.com/r/mU5nD3/1)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How i can use that "(?<=rue|boulevard|quai|chemin).*" ?

Comment: @TheCodor ...are you serious? Have you considered searching for *"python regular expression"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes i have try that:  p = re.compile(ur'(?<=rue|boulevard|quai|chemin).*', re.MULTILINE).        new = re.findall(p, my_list)

Comment: `re.findall` is expecting a *string*, not a *list*. You need to apply the regex separately to each item in your list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for the time but i doen't work i have try                      while i != len(my_list):
            adresse[i] = re.findall(regex, my_list[i])
            i = i + 1
            print adresse
but i have always the error: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: You want me to debug partial code from a badly-formatted comment? Take a hike.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are only extracting one word after you split:

```
adresse = [i.split(' ', 8)[3] for i in my_list`]
```

due to `[3]`.

Try `[3:]` instead. Ah, but that still won't be enough, because you'll get a list of lists, when you want a list of strings. So you also need to use `join`.

```
adresse = [' '.join(i.split(' ', 8)[3:]) for i in my_list`]
```

Now your only difficulty is dealing with irregular street addresses, e.g. people who don't have a house number, or several words in the street name. I have no solution for that!

Comment: Indeed, seems like an impossible problem to solve in it's current state, the selection criteria isn't well-enough defined.

Comment: Why `i.split(' ', 8)[3:]` and not something like `i.split(maxsplit=3)`?