# Use regex to split list in python

Tags: python, regex, list, split

I have a list

```
['toto, 22 monday **HERE MY TEXTE**', 'titi, 23 tuesday **MY SECOND TEXTE**, 'tata, 333 january **MY LAST TEXTE**']
```

I want extract the string in bold, I find my text thanks to string "monday, tuesday, january".

How I can get my text with regex?

Comment: What did you have tried so far? and whats the logic behind your expected output?

Comment: Just loop over your list and apply a regex to each its member.

Comment: I just want get the text that follow "monday or tuesday or january"

Comment: This seems [oddly familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31433377/3001761)... New account?

Answer (score 0):

> I just want get the text that follow "monday or tuesday or january"

```
[re.search(r'(?:^|\s)(?:monday|tuesday|january)\s+(.+)', i).group(1) for i in  lst]
```

**Example:**

```
>>> lst = ['toto, 22 monday **HERE MY TEXTE**', 'titi, 23 tuesday **MY SECOND TEXTE**', 'tata, 333 january **MY LAST TEXTE**']
>>> [re.search(r'(?:^|\s)(?:monday|tuesday|january)\s+(.+)', i).group(1) for i in  lst]
['**HERE MY TEXTE**', '**MY SECOND TEXTE**', '**MY LAST TEXTE**']
```

Comment: I have try your solution but i have AttribeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: what exactly your input is? Check your's and mine.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** regex is not compulsory..

```
mylist = ['toto, 22 monday **HERE MY TEXTE**', 'titi, 23 tuesday **MY SECOND TEXTE**', 'tata, 333 january **MY LAST TEXTE**']

for i in mylist:
    print ' '.join(i.split(' ')[3:])
```

Output:

```
**HERE MY TEXTE**
**MY SECOND TEXTE**
**MY LAST TEXTE**
```

Comment: You have a very good solution but for ['toto in tata, 443 street mytexte', 'titi on lala, 222 street blabla] i get [443 street mytexte] & [222 street blabla]

Comment: if thats a seperate list, you can use `[-1]` instead of `[3:]`